# A once working indexer is now broken and does not rebuild for CDT in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am working on a c++ project using a version of eclipse (Atollic TRUE studio) and this morning my indexer was working just fine. Currently, almost everything is broken (some local things within a file still work, but the rest fails). Googling around told me to do a indexer->rebuild. I have done this is the passed as well and back then it worked just fine. I noticed that, during the indexer rebuild, some progress bar was shown. Now, if I execute the indexer rebuild, nothing happens and I don't see this progress bar anymore. I have not changed any project/workspace/indexer settings, at least not on purpose anyway.

Among others I found this post
[Eclipse indexing not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357009/eclipse-indexing-not-working)
where BЈовић claims

> If this doesn't work, then you are out of luck. c++ is very difficult language to parse.

Is this really the answer? Or is there some smart trick that I missed?

Comment: Are there any exceptions in `<workspace>/.metadata/.log`?

Comment: hmm... There are, something from Atollic. The exception I get is `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`, which comes from SWVClient which looks like a class written by Atollic (that's what the package says). It does not really make any sense though. The SWV is just communication between the application and and a microcontroller, this should not break the Indexer... Is there any change that some plugin that should not do anything with the indexer still could breaks it?

Comment: I agree that the exception you mentioned seems unrelated. I take it there are no other exceptions in the log? Can you give some more details about "almost everything is broken"?

Comment: It's also worth trying the following, which has sometimes fixed strange indexer problems for me in the past: 1) Close Eclipse. 2) Delete the file `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.core/<project>.<timestamp>.pdom` (this is the file that stores the project's index). 3) Start Eclipse again and rebuild the index.

Comment: There where no other exceptions. With "almost everything is broken" I meant that 'ctrl-click' did not work on (as good as) any symbol nor did the highlighting. Also the auto-complete did not work, if I remember correct. A while ago I "fixed" the problem by moving the source into a new project. I guess that is somewhat similar to what you lastly suggested, only what you suggest is slightly less drastic. But both methods feel like a work around.