# Enable C++11 in Eclipse CDT (Juno/Kepler/Luna) indexer

Tags: c++, c++11, eclipse-cdt

How do I enable support for the new C++ standard on the Eclipse CDT indexer in Juno/Kepler/Luna?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The accepted (and correct) answer isn't in that other question.

Comment: @Steve: Johan Lundberg's answer contains the accepted one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13549029/760746

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**Note** that this question (and answer) only deals with the **Eclipse indexer** which is used to highlight errors before compilation takes place. **The C++ compiler settings are not changed!** (Thus, compilation could still fail because of missing C++11 settings, but have a look at the "Related" section)

To change the **Eclipse indexer** settings go to
`Project properties` -> `C/C++ General` -> `Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.` -> tab `Providers` -> `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings`

and append `-std=c++0x` (or `-std=c++11`) to `Command to get compiler specs:`

Afterwards it should look something like:

> ${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD ${INPUTS} -std=c++0x

[image: Screenshot of the configuration pane with the change applied]

**Sources**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#CDT_does_not_recognize_C.2B.2B11_features
- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/373462/909018/#msg_909018

**Related**

- [Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9131763/760746)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499266/760746 (C++11-enable the compiler (Kepler and before))
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22480299/760746 (C++11-enable the compiler (Kepler (updated) and newer)

**Update**

Successfully tested with Eclipse

- Kepler (CDT 8.2)
- Luna (CDT 8.4)

Comment: Additionally, I had to restart Eclipse, before the changes took affect!

Comment: In case anyone else can't get this to work, I also had to add this symbol to Eclipse for some reason: __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__

Comment: Under Kepler, after doing this, I still got the same errors, I needed to rebuild the index before the results were visible to the IDE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008293/clean-eclipse-index-it-is-out-of-sync-with-code

Comment: For Eclipse 4.4 Luna you also have to modify compiler settings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24561615/1169741

Comment: @Trismegistos: Please not that this question is specifically about the indexer and not about the other parts that might be configured to use C++11. Thus, the answer remains the same.

Comment: Yay! worked nicely here after index-rebuild + eclipse-restart. I am using Kepler: Version: Kepler Service Release 2. Build id: 20140224-0627.