# Handling syntax parser errors with NDK C++ code

Tags: android, eclipse, c++11, android-ndk, adt

When I extend an Android project in *Eclipse* by "Native Build support" (don't know what it is called exactly) **and** add C++11 code, I get quite a few errors by the indexer.

When working with pure C++ projects (GCC, LLVM support), I can fix it - but the compiler details are not available with Android native support.

One way to get rid of the problem (and to be able to compile again), is to disable the indexer, but then Eclipse loses it's value.

Is there a better way of fixing this since CDT seems to need at least another year to support C++11 sufficiently.

Comment: To echo @auselen, if you're using a recent enough build of GCC then you should be fine. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13635080/636019) for details on getting CDT's parser to play nice with C++11.

Comment: @ildjarn: No it doesn't. Please if you haven't used Android NDK integration don't try to blind guess the problem.

Comment: @auselen There is only one default compiler for Android NDK.

Comment: There is at least two versions bundled in 8c. It is not possible to understand what you are complaining by "compiler details are not available". Just give -v I would say but I'm sure you are not looking for that.

Comment: @auselen Obviously you also didn't look at the Android NDK integration. The problem is VERY clear if you work with the Android NDK integration. *sigh*

Comment: @LCIDFire : As a matter of fact I have, and do, use the NDK semi-regularly. Don't try to blindly assume you know what works and doesn't when you're the one having trouble. ;-]

Comment: Latest NDK actually includes three compilers. gcc 4.4.3, gcc 4.6 and clang 3.1. And that not counting that both gcc are available for three platforms - arm, mips and x86 (so in total it is 7 compilers).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable C++11 in Eclipse CDT (Juno) indexer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635079/enable-c11-in-eclipse-cdt-juno-indexer)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, since it still does not work (provider and ccnature changes). Making changes to the cpp file still resurfaces the errors (using r8d). It's a mess.