# Cannot find make_shared from std::memory or std::tr1 (gcc 4.7)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc4.7

I don’t understand why I cannot find make_shared from `std::memory or std::tr1` include header.

I only see 1 version of gcc in my machine

```
ls -lh /usr/bin/g++
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Sep 22  2012 /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-4.7
```

And I am using `-std=c++11` tag in the project build property as well

My environment:ubuntu ecplise juno R2 CDT

```
#include <memory>
#include <tr1/memory>
int main()
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> t = std::tr1::make_shared<int>(1);

    std::shared_ptr<int> t = std::make_shared<int>(1);

}
```

Update:

The build in eclipse console window shows it is actually success, but the code editor keep red underline the shared_ptr and make_shared. I tried to rebuild index, clear project. Nothing can remove the error. Any suggestions?

```
16:15:09 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project test ****
make all 
Building target: test 
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "test "  ./main.o   
Finished building target: test 


16:15:09 Build Finished (took 328ms)
```

Update 2:

Below link solved my issue
[Enable C++11 in Eclipse CDT (Juno/Kepler/Luna) indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635079/enable-c11-in-eclipse-cdt-juno-indexer)

Comment: Please add an example program and an example of the `g++` call used to compile it.

Comment: Your code works well(second case) even with g++ 4.6.3([LWS example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1r1dcl$0)).

Comment: The "works well" case has an interesting difference in compiler options: `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: @BoPersson, it's because g++ 4.6.3 doesn't know about `-std=c++11` option, but g++ 4.7 does.

Comment: Build was success, but eclipse keep showing errors...

Comment: The Update has changed your question completely. You should change the title and focus on your actual problem, e.g. remove the misleading introduction, show a screenshot (since it is a representational problem), et cetera.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635079/enable-c11-in-eclipse-cdt-juno-indexer

Solution from this link solved my problem