# How to enable C++11 in Eclipse Juno/Kepler/Luna CDT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-luna

EDIT: It turns out this really isn't specific to Eclipse Kepler. I had to use the same process for Eclipse Juno. The problem was that there seem to be missing steps in other posts answering this same question.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler for C++ and I'm trying to use C++11 and getting errors. When I compile I get the error

error: range-based-for loops are not allowed in C++98 mode

I've followed the instructions from the post

[Eclipse CDT C++11/C++0x support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support)

and the solution given for Eclipse Juno isn't working.

Different comments have suggested restarting eclipse and cleaning and rebuilding. That hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

There's two things you have to do, first you need to setup your compiler, then you need to setup CDT's language processor.  Since you didn't mention which compiler you're using, I'll assume it's GCC but the steps will be similar for other compilers.  (Note that you need a compiler that supports C++11, of course.)

Setting up the compiler is fairly straightforward:

1. Right click your project and click Properties
2. Under C/C++ Build click Settings
3. Under GCC C++ Compiler, click Miscellaneous
4. In the Other Flags box, append "-std=c++11" to the list of tokens.
5. Click Apply and OK

At this point you should be able to rebuild your project and get it to run.  But CDT still may show errors for C++11 includes.  Here's how you can resolve that:

1. Right click your project and click Properties
2. Under C/C++ General click "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros"
3. Select the Providers tab
4. There should be an item in the list that says something like "GCC Built in Compiler Settings". Select this entry.
5. Uncheck the "Use global provider..." option
6. Under the list there's an box that says "Command to get compiler specs."  Append "-std=c++0x" to this.
7. Move the "GCC Built in Compiler Settings" provider at the top of the list using the 'Move Up' button on the right.
8. Click Apply and then OK.
9. Back in your Eclipse workspace, select the Project Menu, C/C++ Index, and click "Re-resolve unresolved includes."

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Maybe I misread the other post I linked to, but it seems that there was no mention of setting up the compiler in that post.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. My main problem is the unresolved c++11 includes. I put `-std=c++11` in where you said to put, and rebuilt the full index, still shows a crapload of unrecognized std::cout, std::set, etc…

Comment: EDIT: I didn't find the first part where it should, but I'm compiling through make, so it may be an explanation. (I found it in workspace configuration though and set it). But I put it in the `compiler spec`, and still doesn’t work. std::shared_ptr and same not recognized. Though it used to work on the older machine with juno.

Comment: In my case(gcc) I used -std=c++0x. So everything is working. Thank you!

Comment: You might need to restart eclipse if it doesn't work once you've made the changes.

Comment: @MrEricSir is there a way to make this setting for workspace so that when I add a new project it is automatically applied to it too?

Comment: have been searching for days, i'm a java developer and new to C++ and was stuck at this point, the tutorial is done with C++11 and Eclipse is stopping me, thanks alot ... and please if you have any links or resources that help me learn C++ (i'm heading to learn windows phone) please let me know ... thanks

Comment: @EL-conteDe-monteTereBentikh Glad to hear I could help setting up your workspace, but I can't recommend any specific tutorials myself, nor would it be within StackOverflow's policies for me to do so.  That said, you're lucky enough to learn computer programming in the information age -- try your favorite search engine, your local libraries and bookstores, or inquiring at colleges and universities.

Comment: And this is why I stopped using Eclipse for all my other non-C++ development: honestly, does one really need all this grief, when a "Use C++11" checkbox in Preferences would suffice?

Comment: Goddamn kepler moved the misc tab out of the settings window. Sometimes I love eclipse, and sometimes....

Comment: @ScubaSteve Do you know where they moved it to? I have Neon and I'm still looking...

Comment: @jwimberley - Honestly, unless you have to use a specific compiler, just use .Net and Visual Studio 2015. Eclipse is a sad joke by comparison.

Answer (score 25):

**C++11 support in Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1 (Build id: 20130919-0819)**

In the latest release Eclipse Kepler SR1 you only have to add *-std=c++11*

1. Right click on your project and click **Properties**
2. Navigate to **C/C++ General** and **Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.**
3. Select the **Providers** tab
4. Add **-std=c++11** to *Command to get compiler specs:*
5. Apply changes, the Index should be generated automatically.

The *"Command to get compiler specs:"*-line should look like:

```
${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}" -std=c++11
```

Comment: With GCC I had to add -std=c++0x

Comment: Which GCC do you use? c++0X was the old name (alias) for C++11

Comment: Found this a second time setting up a fresh eclipse CDT - setting this up should be more intuitive.

Answer (score 13):

As of CDT 8.3 ([available as a Kepler update](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php)), there is a new dialect option in build settings:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn83#Build

Answer (score 6):

I use Eclipse Kepler and to fix it i did this:

1 - Right-Click the Project >> Proprietes >> C/C++ Build :: Settings

2 - Went to GCC G++ Compiler >> Miscellaneous >> Other Flags

I then added `-std=c++11`, hit apply and ok

That fixed my problem!

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is the best answer for Eclipse Platform, Version: 4.3.1 - Don't know what Kepler/Juno is!

Comment: Eclipse Kepler is Eclipse Version 4.3.X

Answer (score 4):

Running eclipse indigo and cdt 8.0.2 here. I followed all the guides, but it was still necessary to set the preprocessor define by hand to find things like std::unique_ptr.
The include file "memory" checks this.
Set __cplusplus to 201103L on the  "Symbols" tab under "Paths and Symbols" in "C++ General" in project properties.

Comment: Yes, Works for migrations from old projects.

Answer (score 2):

Adding dialect flag "-std=c++11" to Project properties-> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool settings (GCC C++ Compiler -> Dialect) solved my problem in Eclipse Kepler, apart from the settings stated above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse Luna and there is no "Tool Settings" under C/C++ Build -> Settings.  I *DID* add -std=c++11 to the compiler specs command line under "C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Includes -> Providers" as suggested.  But that still did not satisfy my indexer's ability to resolve emplace().

So I looked in the header file for  and found that the emplace functions are dependent on __cplusplus >= 201103L.  So I just added the preprocessor symbol "__cplusplus" and gave it the value 201103.

Kinda hackish but the indexer is happy.  (And makefiles define my build flags, not the eclipse project)