# Range based loops: Auto changes meaning in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I was trying to make a range based lopp like this in C++11:

```
std::vector<Satellite> Satellites; // Class member
//...

int number = 1;
for(auto sat : this->Satellites) {
    sat.setNumber(number++);
}
```

And I'm getting this warning:

> 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]

Of course I could stick to `for(Satellite sat : this->Satellites)`, but I was trying to test the auto keyword.

I had read that usage of auto was possible with C++11, but [recently I found](http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/the-biggest-changes-in-c11-and-why-you-should-care/) that it changed since C++0x (or it looks like it did!):

> The keyword auto isn’t new; it actually dates back the pre-ANSI C era.
>   However, C++11 has changed its meaning; auto no longer designates an
>   object with automatic storage type. Rather, it declares an object
>   whose type is deducible from its initializer. The old meaning of auto
>   was removed from C++11 to avoid confusion.

So: Am I able to use it like this with C++11 and my problem is at the IDE (Eclipse CDT Juno), or should I use it in a different way (or remove the auto keyword at all)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage is "fine" in C++11, and is invalid syntax in C++03.

The only potential problem is that you are making a copy of each `Satellite`, which is not necessarily what you want. You may get a reference like this:

```
for(const auto& sat : this->Satellites) { ....
```

or

```
for(auto& sat : this->Satellites) { ....
```

if you want mutable references to the vector's elements.

You should check whether your compiler fully supports this feature. Whereas it is valid C++11, the warning suggests and old pre-C++11 standard compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the advice avoiding copies!

I have cpp 4.8.1, so I think my compiler version is fine. So the problem must be at the Makefile (if CDT Juno still uses it, because I don't know for sure: I had to add every src folder into project properties, which wasn't necessary in older CDT version). Maybe I'm missing some flag at the project properties?

Comment: Aaaaand, sure I was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457069/enabling-c11-in-eclipse-juno-kepler-cdt

Answer (score 0):

You were compiling with a non'11 compiler, that's why you got the message.