# Use built-in c++ structures

Tags: c++, hash, tuples, built-in

I'm working on a project using Eclipse for C++. Currently I need to use structures such as tuples and hashes. When looking for it on the cplusplus site i came with these:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/?kw=tuple

The point is, following the example code on the site when trying to compile I get an error, which says, for example, that tuple is not defined. Looking more closely, the c++ sites says these features work on revision 11 and newer. Maybe this can be my problem since I have no idea how to check my version.

How do I get to work with the last revision? I'd really help me a lot not having to implement these kind of structures from scratch.

EDIT: i did g++ --version on the console and got:

g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Im using Ubuntu 12.04 with Eclipse C/C++ Kepler SR2

EDIT with answer:

Tu use the c11 standard, gcc 4.7 is needed. Refer to this link: http://www.swiftsoftwaregroup.com/upgrade-gcc-4-7-ubuntu-12-04/

to install it.

Comment: You have to enable c++11, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457069/enabling-c11-in-eclipse-juno-kepler-cdt

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you on?

Answer (score 1):

compile with `std=c++11`, like  `g++ -std=c++11 program.cpp` . `tuple` is indeed newly introduced in `C++11`, but you can use `maps` and `sets` in `C++03` (the `unordered` versions are again a new feature of the standard library that comes with `C++11`).  In eclipse, go to project properties, `C/C++ Build/Settings/C++ compiler/Miscellaneous`, then add the `-std=c++11` flag

Comment: Ok, I thought that one knows how to change the compiler. Go to project properties, `C/C++ Build/Settings/C++ compiler/Miscellaneous`, then add the `-std=c++11` flag

Comment: I get an error with this. It says cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’

Comment: Then it means your compiler doesn't support C++11. What platform are you using? Can you open a terminal and type `g++ --version` (or `c++ --version`)?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Im using Ubuntu 12.04 with Eclipse C/C++ Kepler SR2