# C++ Build successful but Eclipse keeps showing errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, cross-compiling, raspbian

I'm having some trouble with my Eclipse.

I've included the  library into my project. The Cross GCC compiler seems to compile everything pretty well.

Console output:

```
14:37:50 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project DomoHome2 ****
make all 
Building target: DomoHome2
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++  -o "DomoHome2"  ./BV4618.o ./Database.o ./main.o   -    lmysqlclient -lwiringPi -lz -ldl -lpthread
Finished building target: DomoHome2


14:37:51 Build Finished (took 114ms)
```

But eclipse still shows these errors:

```
Type 'thread' could not be resolved BV4618.cpp  /DomoHome2  line 235    Semantic Error
```

I've tried many solutions like refreshing the indexer files, or changing the code analysis but i'm still getting this annoying error. What should I do?

Solved following these instructions:

Right click your project and click Properties
Under C/C++ General click "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros"
Select the Providers tab
There should be an item in the list that says something like "GCC Built in Compiler Settings". Select this entry.
Uncheck the "Use global provider..." option
Under the list there's an box that says "Command to get compiler specs." Append "-std=c++0x" to this.
Click Apply and then OK.
Back in your Eclipse workspace, select the Project Menu, C/C++ Index, and click *"Re-resolve unresolved includes."

*Rebuild the Indexer files before doing it

Comment: This happens because eclipse has its own C++ parser instead of g++ and it is this build in parser that gives this error. There are already many questions addressing this problem but there is not a simple solution AFAIK what works for some doesn't work for others. Search on eclipse C++ 11 to find these questions and try out the solutions offered.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved using the second part of this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17499266/2739814