# Eclipse CDT enabling c++ 11 problems

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to follow the instructions from [Enabling C++11 in Eclipse Juno/Kepler/Luna CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457069/enabling-c11-in-eclipse-juno-kepler-cdt), but I'm having some difficulties, since I don't have a "Preprocessor Include Paths" tab..

How can I get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I solved this issue by downgrading the CDT plugin (was 8.1.2, d/g to 8.0.2).
Apperantly there were some compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your C++ project in the Project Explorer (left-hand-side listview in the C/C++ View of Eclipse CDT) brings up a popup menu, at the bottom of which you'll find the "Properties" entry.

That brings up a requester with a listview on the left:

```
> Resource
  Builders
> C/C++ Build
> C/C++ General          // <--
  Project References
  Run/Debug Settings
```

Expand "C/C++ General":

```
v C/C++ General
  > Code Analysis
    Documentation
    File Types
    Formatter
    Indexer
    Language Mappings
    Paths and Symbols
    Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.   // <--
```

Selecting that will change the available settings on the right-hand side of the dialog.

If you cannot follow this, please be more precise at which point of the sequence, exactly, your Eclipse shows something different, and what that might be.

Comment: As I wrote: I don't have that tab.. The last option after "Language Mappings" is "Paths and Symbols".

Comment: @YonadavSchleifer: Sorry, "tab" had me guessing you might have confused things, as it's not a tab (at least not in the 3.8 I have here). Cannot help you at this point, but will leave the answer open as clarification.