# 'function' does not name a type (in Eclipse)

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++

I am using the library `<functional>` which defines the class `function`. But when I try to compile the code I get an error that `function` does not name a type.

Till recently I was using Microsoft Visual Studio and there was no problem. Now I sometimes work on Ubuntu 14.04 with Eclipse and g++ and got this error when compiling the same code (except the 'main').

I found here some similar problems but none of the solution works for me.

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

typedef function<double(double, double*)> t_function;
```

error on third line, I also tried different (and no namespaces) with different using and none works

Comment: `using std::function`? Show us the code

Comment: @Michal Again, show a [MCVE] please.

Comment: What version is your gcc? Also, are you compiling in c++11 mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have an old version of gcc (less likely), or not compiling in c++11 mode (more likely), which is enabled with a compiler flag:

> C++11 features are available as part of "mainline" GCC in the trunk of GCC's repository and in GCC 4.3 and later. To enable C++0x support, add the command-line parameter -std=c++0x to your g++ command line. Or, to enable GNU extensions in addition to C++0x extensions, add -std=gnu++0x. GCC 4.7 and later support -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11 as well.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457069/enabling-c11-in-eclipse-juno-kepler-luna-cdt) describes the process of enabling c++11 in Eclipse in-detail, though it is rather old.

Comment: I got a bunch of different errors but not the original one with `function`