# Eclipse producing error warning but compiler says 'no'

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2) and I get an error message warning:

"Function 'next' could not be resolved"

I have included support for c++11 (used this: [Enabling C++11 in Eclipse Juno/Kepler/Luna CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457069/enabling-c11-in-eclipse-juno-kepler-luna-cdt)) but I still get the warning which is very misleading.

Includes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
```

Code:

```
std::vector<int> myvector;

...

void feefiefoefoo(int** matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    int vec_size = myvector.size();
    int column_pointer = 0;
    auto it = myvector.begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = column_pointer; j < vec_size; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = *it;
            it = std::next(it); // **THIS IS THE LINE**
        }

        column_pointer++;
        vec_size++;
        it = myvector.begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you [`#include <iterator>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)?

Comment: @WhiZTiM Yes, I updated my answer with all the includes.

Comment: What is the type of `it`?

Comment: Is vec_size supposed to be cols? cols is unused

Comment: We need to see the definition of `myvetor.begin();`

Comment: Replacing `auto` with `std::vector<int>::iterator` (the actual type) does not remove the error.

Comment: Adding `std::vector<int> myvetor;` above the function. It compiles for me. g++ 5.1.0

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes it compiles for me too, but eclipse produces an error *warning* . I know... it sounds like a contradiction using those two terms together :)

Comment: Sorry but we are going to enter opinion territory here: Eclipse CDT is not very good at parsing C++11 and beyond and can give false errors/warnings.  Eclipse CDT does not use the compiler engine you use to do your compilations but its own parser, it gets things wrong on occasion.

Comment: @RichardCritten 1) That's not helping with the question. 2) If you feel Eclipse CDT is lacking something you should at least recommend an alternative that is not lacking those features.