# How to configure Eclipse CDT to recognise C++ keywords?

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, configuration, eclipse-cdt

I am using the latest release of Eclipse CDT to develop a C++11 static library.

Everything's going fine, except the syntax highlighter doesn't recognise some keywords, namely `#include` statements.

Has anyone fixed this issue?

Comment: Maybe your color theme doesn't define any specific color for #include? Have a look at http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/ and the associated eclipse plugin (it's great). In addition you might need to do the following to make sure Eclipse understands some of the new C++11 features: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635079/enable-c11-in-eclipse-cdt-juno-kepler-indexer

Comment: It does, they're just underlined.

Comment: Do they have "bug" symbols in front of them? As in, is the static analyzer causing the "errors"?

Comment: They're marked as "Unresolved inclusion". The symbol is a question mark.

Comment: Found a fix here in SO. Can you vote to close my question?

Comment: Could you link to the answer?

Comment: The link is in the header.