# Eclipse CDT Indexer does not fully recognize c++11

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt

First of all, I know about the -std=c++11 flag to enable c++11 support and where to place it. I've appended `-std=c++11` to `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous -> Other Flags` and compiling just works fine. But the indexer doesn't get along, for example if I want to use the `emplace` function of `std::map` (c++11), it will not find the emplace function.

```
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> data;
    data.emplace(5,5);
```

I've also checked out these related questions:

- [Eclipse CDT indexer does not know C++11 containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers)
- [Enable C++11 in Eclipse CDT (Juno/Kepler/Luna) indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635079/enable-c11-in-eclipse-cdt-juno-kepler-luna-indexer)
- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/373462/909018/#msg_909018

Update: Now that I've played around it even doesn't recognize the std::map type, although compiling fine and eclipse finding all headers...

- Compiler Mingw64 GCC 5.2.0
- Eclipse Mars 4.5
- CDT 8.7

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers/24628885#24628885

Comment: Tried that one, too... also tried under eclipse luna cdt 8.6... seems to be a indexer bug with std::map... will propably report on eclipse forums and link to that one

Comment: There was an indexer bug but its fixed now. Did you try updating your plugins? `Help -> Check For Updates` from the menu.

Comment: Well I was under the impression the fix for the indexer bug was released by now. I fixed it in my eclipse by updating to the current development version (experimental). The *update site* for that is here: Nightly - http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/master/nightly/ use at your own risk :)

Comment: God thanks! That shit was annoying as hell <3
But i'm surprised by the slightly changed interface... is there a site or something which will cover the changes and features? :)

Comment: Its such a debilitating bug I assumed they would push it through quickly. Apparently not. IIRC the bug only surfaced with the upgrade to `GCC 5.2`, some change in `GCC` a library header I believe.

Comment: I think because GCC 5 (.1 or .2 doesn't really matter, 2 is just bugfix) is the first gcc to introduce full feature c++11

Answer (score 8):

Eclipse Mars does it a bit differently than the previous versions.

Step one gets the indexer error highlighting working - covered in [Enable C++11 in Eclipse CDT (Juno/Kepler/Luna) indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635079/enable-c11-in-eclipse-cdt-juno-kepler-luna-indexer) linked above. If you've already done all this, I'll be smurfed if I know what you've run into. Mars has been a bit wonky so far.

1. Go to Project->properties->C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths.
2. Click the Providers tab.
3. Click CDT GCC Built-in Compiler settings MinGW
4. Click Move Up button on the right.
5. Under Language Settings Provider Options

   1. Click off Use Global provider shared between projects
   2. Add -std=c++1y to the end of the command line in Command to get compiler specs.

By the way, if anyone knows where the global settings are so I can default this behaviour, please let me know.

Step 2 gets the compiler working

1. Go to Project->properties->C/C++ Build->Settings.
2. Go to Tool Settings tab.
3. Expand GCC C++ Compiler
4. Click Dialect
   Pick the C++ Standard you wish to target from the Language Standard drop-down.

Comment: Besides that your step 1 doesn't help in my case, you can do that one under `Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery`... this problem is really nasty, i'll propably try another CDT Version...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, glad you could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT understands the C++ code in a window by running it through an indexer. This indexer is nothing but an invocation of the GCC C++ compiler with certain compilation options. Sometimes, you might want to change the compiler options used by this indexer.

For example, I recently found that C++11 containers and classes (like future) were not resolved by the indexer and were underlined with red squiggles. This is because the compiler options used by the indexer does not have -std=c++11.

To change the compiler options of the indexer:

1. Open Preferences and go to C/C++ -> Build -> Settings.
2. Click the Discovery tab and choose CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings.
3. Modify the command string shown below it as you wish. For example, here I added -std=c++11.
4. Eclipse CDT will automatically re-index your C++
   files after this is saved. However, I found that this did not remove
   the unresolved items.
5. I manually re-indexed by right-clicking the
   project and choosing Index -> Rebuild. This worked!

Comment: "This indexer is nothing but an invocation of the GCC C++ compiler with certain compilation options." is very misleading. It's true that CDT's Built-in Compiler Settings provider will invoke GCC with certain compilation options - but that's done with an empty file as input, and the only purpose is to discover built-in include paths and #defines. The actual code in the project is processed by CDT's own parser and code analyzer.