# Eclipse CDT: cannot resolve 'begin' and 'end' symbols in foreach-loop

Tags: c++11, foreach, eclipse-cdt

The indexer of eclipse CDT does not properly recognize the 'end' and 'begin' symbols needed in a foreach loop whenever I want to directly iterate over data returned by a function. It works when I first put the result into a temporary variable.

MWE:

```
#include "mwe.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto tmp = do_something();
    for(auto &x : tmp){ } //Working
    for(auto &x : do_something()){ } //Symbol 'end'/'begin' could not be resolved
}
```

mwe.h:

```
#include<iterator>

class X { };
class Handle { };
class MyIterator: public std::iterator<X, std::input_iterator_tag> {
public:
    explicit MyIterator(Handle &iter) : iter_(&iter) { }
    MyIterator() { }
    MyIterator &operator++() { return *this; }
    MyIterator operator++(int) { return *this;  }
    X &operator*() { return x;  }
    X *operator->() { return &**this; }
    friend bool operator==(MyIterator a, MyIterator b) { return true; }
    friend bool operator!=(MyIterator a, MyIterator b) { return false; }
private:
    Handle *iter_;
    X x;
};

inline MyIterator begin(Handle &it) { return MyIterator(it); }
inline MyIterator end(Handle &) { return MyIterator(); }

Handle do_something() { return Handle(); }
```

The code compiles and works with no errors, only the indexer tells me that it does not find the symbols. That said, fixing the problem is not really necessary but it is quite annoying.

Additional note: I already checked many other Questions regarding the Indexer in CDT but the answers didn't fix my problem:

[Eclipse CDT Indexer does not fully recognize c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642375/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-fully-recognize-c11)

[Eclipse CDT: Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803685/eclipse-cdt-symbol-cout-could-not-be-resolved?newreg=7fe8a3cc211d461784fbf1b62ffe82a6)

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/636348/

Is there a problem with the code or is it a (known) bug in CDT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the definition of `begin`

```
inline MyIterator begin(Handle &it) { return MyIterator(it); }
```

we see that it takes a reference to a non-constant object. That means you can not pass temporary objects to the function. Like what happens when using `do_something()` directly. The quick solution is to add an overload that take an *rvalue reference* instead:

```
inline MyIterator begin(Handle &&it) { return MyIterator(it); }
//                             ^^
//     Note double ampersand here
```

---

There are other possible pitfalls with your code though, especially since `do_something` returns by value. That means each call to `do_something` will return a separate object, and if `do_something` is called more than once you will have different objects with different data.

Also note that [`std::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) have been deprecated in the C++17 standard. You should specialize [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) instead if you want the common types.

Comment: Thanks, that does work! However, I am still wondering why it compiles properly (both in G++ 5 and MSVC). Also thanks for the additional comments!

Comment: @0xfull I don't know why it apparently worked on GCC 5, but MSVC++ have a non-standard extension to the language that allows temporary objects to be bound to non-const references.

Comment: The code compiles not only with GCC 5, but also newer versions, and Clang. I believe it's conforming, and the OP has found a bug in Eclipse CDT.

Comment: Please see my answer where I explain why this code is actually well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

The code in question is actually conforming. It compiles with recent versions of gcc and clang.

The flaw in the other answer is that it does not take into account the rewrite that the compiler performs on the range-based for loop.

`[stmt.ranged] p1` says:

> The range-based for statement
>
> `for ( init-statement_opt for-range-declaration : for-range-initializer) statement`
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     init-statement_opt
>     auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
>     auto __begin = begin-expr ;
>     auto __end = end-expr ;
>     for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
>         for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>         statement
>     }
> }
> ```

So, in this case, `for(auto &x : do_something()){ }` is rewritten to:

```
{
    auto &&__range = do_something();
    auto __begin = begin(__range);
    auto __end = end(__range);
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
        auto &x = *__begin;
    }
}
```

Notice that the actual arguments to the calls to `begin()` and `end()` are not the expression `do_something()` itself, but a hidden (notional) variable `__range`. Since `__range` is a named variable, it's an **lvalue** in expression context, and the lvalue reference parameter of `begin()` and `end()` will bind to it successfully.

---

That Eclipse CDT gives an error on this code is a bug, which I've just [filed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538517), and will fix shortly.