# Eclipse CDT flags up a semantic error with forward delaclaration, but compiles with no errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

Is there a way to configure Eclipse so that it can resolve the following forward declaration example? 
This builds without any problems.

```
class MyClass {
public:
  enum class MyEnum; // Forward declaration.
  enum class MyOtherEnum {
    DELTA,
    ECHO,
    FOXTROT
  };
};

enum class MyClass::MyEnum{
  ALPHA,
  BRAVO,
  CHARLIE
};

int main(void) {
  volatile MyClass::MyEnum myVariable = MyClass::MyEnum::BRAVO; // Flags up two semantic errors.
  volatile MyClass::MyOtherEnum myOtherVariable = MyClass::MyOtherEnum::ECHO; // No problems.
  return 0;
}
```

Semantic Errors: 
Symbol 'BRAVO' could not be resolved. 
Type 'MyClass::MyEnum' could not be resolved.

Using Eclipse CDT Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

Comment: Because Eclipse wants to be too clever... It analyses the code itself instead of letting the compiler do the job. So you must be sure to set the correct C++ level in Eclipse (C++ 98, 11, 14, ...). If it is not enough either throw Eclipse away, or fully define MyEnum inside the class...

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks for the information. I just tried setting the version using the process outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635079/enable-c11-in-eclipse-cdt-juno-kepler-luna-indexer, but no luck unfortunately. I guess they overlooked enums as it works with nested structs and classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug and is fixed in the upcoming Neon release of Eclipse CDT.

[Duplicate Bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490592#c1)