# Eclipse Juno - not parsing C++11, current SO solutions doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, c++11

So far I have tried these tricks: (from other SO questions)

1. C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous -> Other Flags. Put -std=c++0x (or for newer compiler version -std=c++11 at the end)
2. C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Symbols -> GNU C++. Click "Add..." and paste **GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X** (ensure to append and prepend two underscores) into "Name" and leave "Value" blank.
3. [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635079/enable-c11-in-eclipse-cdt-juno-kepler-luna-indexer)

Other noticeable things:

1. When I open C++11 header like `<memory>` it is visible that `__cplusplus` macro shadows the text below it, including `<backward/auto_ptr.h>` instead of all C++11 stuff; hovering mouse over macro shows that `__cplusplus` expands to `199711L`
2. parser has no problems with this lines:

`int* p = nullptr;`

`virtual void InheritedFunction() override;`

3. It seems that parser understands correctly C++11 features (lambdas work) but somehow things like `std::shared_ptr` are blocked by not-including appropriate headers because `__cplusplus` macro expands wrong
4. Eclipse can't resolve my external libraries #includes. All paths are correct, they are the same as before reinstalling Eclipse
5. \/

[image] "The settings are not used by indexer" - but why? Also I don't have anything like "MBS" on the providers tab

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing so many things in settings that I don't remember for sure what was the actual cause.

Probably this:
Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer -> Build configuration for the indexer

I changed from "Use build configuration specified in the project's indexer settings" to "Use active build configuration"

Somehow the "The settings are not used by indexer" has disappeared and I can freely edit `__cplusplus` value now

Also, my unresolved external libraries are now found