# Can Eclipse be configured to support C++14?

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++14

Forgive me if this is trivial, but I'm trying to get back to C++ after a long time and am having trouble configuring Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1a to support C++14. Is it possible to enable C++14 support in Eclipse at all?

The [April 2017 Eclipse newsletter](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/april/article3.php) states that "CDT's support for C++14 is a work in progress", but I don't know if this still holds.

Here's what I tried. Under `File → Properties → C/C++ Build → GCC C++ Compiler → Dialect`, there's a built-in setting where I set `Language standard` to `ISO C++1y (-std=c++1y)`, but this doesn't seem to help as even features such as `std::shared_ptr` are not recognized by Eclipse. I tried entering `-std=c++14` into `Other dialect flags`, but to no avail. I also tried the proposed solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support), but again with no success.

I have gcc 5.4.0.

Is it possible to get C++14 working with Eclipse Oxygen?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support

Comment: @AmeyaVS I referred to the exact same post in my question and mentioned that it doesn't solve my problem. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: When you add the compilation flag to the compiler configuration it will pass it to the compiler, you would have no issue building the project. But there is also a eclipse parser which also needs to be configured with the option. Will update once I remember where.

Comment: Possible solution available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635079/enable-c11-in-eclipse-cdt-juno-kepler-luna-indexer).