# eclipse c++ using namespace could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying c++ in eclipse for the first time. I loaded some c++ code from an open source project which uses armadillo and rcpp. I managed to get the code to get past including  and  using c/c++ Build -> settings popup. Now it gets stuck on 
    using namespace arma;
    using namespace Rcpp;

Both get errors like symbol 'arma' could not be resolved. How to get past this point?

Comment: Do you have the source code for armadillo and rcpp or are those already compiled libraries?

Comment: If they are compiled libraries they you need to add the libraries to your project. Go to Project-->Properties-->C/C++ General-->Paths and Symbols Libraries tab and add the path to the library files.

Comment: I added both to the libraries and library paths tabs.

Comment: Sorry. all I had to do is to do project -> build. Like I said, the first time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003438/eclipse-cdt-project-with-armadillo-cdt-does-not-recognize-arma-namespace?rq=1 is this the one you are searching for