# Eclipse F3 points to old Environment Variable location

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

Before an update we have an environment variable set to point a folder. In this folder there is an access to command header definitions via F3. (We are using CDT.)

After an update, I change the environment variable to look at new position. But F3 still looks at the old path location. At this point F3 in header files point to right update folder, but F3 in printf or other function element points to old before update item.

Any Idea about how F3 via eclipse user environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. Eclipse reads system environment variables at startup. You need to re-start Eclipse after any changes to environment variables.
2. CDT has an option to re-index your projects. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008293/clean-eclipse-index-it-is-out-of-sync-with-code).